# Access Violation error in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have been trying to resolve the access violation in the program for bounding volume hierarchy. I get an access violation error while running it. I have used SDL and lib3d packages.

> Error: Unhandled exception at 0x00fa2e80 in bvh.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

Call Stack :> `bvh.exe!Triangle::Triangle(const Vertex * vertexA, const Vertex * vertexB, const Vertex * vertexC, unsigned int r, unsigned int g, unsigned int b, bool twosided, bool triNormalProvided, Float3 triNormal)` Line 393 + 0x150 bytes C++

I have defined my structures in the following manner:

```
struct Float3 
{
   float X, Y Z;
   Float3(float x=0, float y=0, float z=0)
        :
    X(x), Y(y), Z(z){} 

   Float3(const Float3& rhs)
        :
    X(rhs.X), Y(rhs.Y), Z(rhs.Z){}

    inline Float3& operator+=(const Float3& rhs)
    {
    X += rhs.X; Y += rhs.Y; Z += rhs.Z; return *this;
    }

    // similar for the other operators

    void assignSmaller(const Float3& rhs)
   {
        X = min(X, rhs.X);
        Y = min(Y, rhs.Y); 
        Z = min(Z, rhs.Z);
    }

   void assignBigger(const Float3& rhs)
        {
        X = max(X, rhs.X);
        Y = max(Y, rhs.Y);
        Z = max(Z, rhs.Z);
        }

    float length()
    {
    return sqrt(X*X +Y*Y + Z*Z);
    }

    inline float lengthsq()
    {
    return X*X +Y*Y + Z*Z;
    }

    inline void Normalize()
    {
    float norm = length();
    X/= norm; Y/= norm; Z/= norm;
    }
};

struct Vertex : public Float3
{
    Float3 n;
    unsigned _ambientOcclusionCoeff;

    Vertex(float x, float y, float z, float nx, float ny, float nz, unsigned char amb=60)
    :
    Float3(x,y,z), n(nx,ny,nz), _ambientOcclusionCoeff(amb){}

};

struct Pixel {
    float _b, _g, _r;
    Pixel(float r=0.f, float g=0.f, float b=0.f)
    :
    _b(b), _g(g), _r(r) {}

Pixel& operator+=(const Pixel& rhs) { _b += rhs._b; _g += rhs._g; _r += rhs._r; return *this; }
     // similar for the other operators

};

struct Triangle
{
    const Vertex *_vertexA, *_vertexB, *_vertexC;
    Float3 centroid, n; 
    // Color: 
    Pixel _colorf; 
    // precomputed for SDL surface
    Uint32 _color;

    // Should we backface cull this triangle?
    bool _twoSided;

    // Raytracing intersection pre-computed cache:
    float _d, _d1, _d2, _d3;
    Float3 _e1, _e2, _e3, _bottom, _top;

    Triangle(
    const Vertex *vertexA,
        const Vertex *vertexB,
    const Vertex *vertexC,
    unsigned r, unsigned g, unsigned b,
    bool twosided = false, bool triNormalProvided=false,
    Float3 triNormal=Float3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f)) 
     :

    _vertexA(vertexA), _vertexB(vertexB), _vertexC(vertexC),

    centroid((vertexA->X + vertexB->X + vertexC->X)/3.0f,
         (vertexA->Y + vertexB->Y + vertexC->Y)/3.0f,
         (vertexA->Z + vertexB->Z + vertexC->Z)/3.0f),

    _colorf((float)r,(float)g,(float)b), // For use in all other cases
    _color(SDL_MapRGB(Screen::_surface->format, r,g,b)), // For use with DrawPixel

    _twoSided(twosided),

     _bottom(FLT_MAX,FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX), // Will be updated after centering in Loader
     _top(-FLT_MAX, -FLT_MAX,-FLT_MAX) // Will be updated after centering in Loader
    {
         // this is where the debugger points to with an access violation error.
        if (!triNormalProvided) 
         {
        n = Float3((vertexA->n.X + vertexB->n.X + vertexC->n.X)/3.0f,
               (vertexA->n.Y + vertexB->n.Y + vertexC->n.Y)/3.0f,
               (vertexA->n.Z + vertexB->n.Z + vertexC->n.Z)/3.0f);
        n.Normalize();
         }
       else {n = triNormal;}
        }
};
```

Comment: Gonna need some code if you want real help

Comment: Yes. You disable compiling and don't run the program.

Comment: Instead of asking how to get the environment to ignore your bugs post some code snippets identifying the problem and ask us how to fix the bugs ... just a thought :P

Comment: You are probably dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311695/access-violation-error-in-c)?

Comment: I wish i know where the bug is :( @AJG85

Answer (score 8):

You don't "avoid access violation error" by changing settings in your IDE.

You resolve these faults by fixing your code. You are corrupting memory somewhere, dereferencing an invalid pointer, writing/reading past the end of a buffer, `free`ing memory that was already freed....

Comment: Two of your suggestions are not correct. It can't be writing past the end of the buffer (its such a low #) and it can't be freeing free'd memory as far as I know for this case (I don't see there being any reason for that to try to access `4` which will almost never by any means dereference correctly)

Comment: @mathepic: It was a general comment regarding access violations.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're trying to access the second member variable of the Triangle in that member function, and the `this` pointer is NULL.

Or maybe once of those vertex pointers passed in is NULL.

As an example, this would produce the error you are seeing:

```
struct Foo
{
    void bar() { cout << b << end; }
    int a, b;
};

int main()
{
    Foo* f = 0;
    f->bar();
    return 0;
}
```

The access to `b` in `bar()` would is effectively an access to an `int` offset by `4` (`sizeof(int)`) to `this`. If `this` is `NULL` (as it is in the example) then you would get an access violation at location 0x00000004.

Ensure that all your pointers are valid.

Comment: the values for the vertex comes from a file and i'm sure that it does'nt have any NULL values

Comment: @user: Not NULL values, NULL pointers. Somewhere in your code you must be creating `Vertex` and `Triangle` objects and calling functions on them. At some point, you are probably calling the function with a pointer that hasn't been initialised.

Comment: Thank you, Peter Alexander! Your explanation was clear enough that I could fix a related error in my code :)

Answer (score 4):

I seriously doubt that `0x00000004` is pointing to something. Usually numbers like that don't; they are too "normal". You can't dereference an `int`.